# How distribute repeated value in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, distribution

I'm looking to distribute all repeated value in an array. (I don't know what name is appropriate to describe that).

I will explain you with an example.

I have an array with duplicated values :

IN :

```
['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bli', 'bli']
```

I would like an array with all values distributed. Have a maximum of field/space between 2 repetition of a value.

OUT :

```
['foo', 'bar', 'bli', 'foo', 'bar', 'bli']
```

If you prefer with an array containing number could also be good for me :

IN :

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

OUT :

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

In the worse scenario I can have several uniq value with several duplicated value X time.

If someone have an algorithm name or an implementation to do that (Python would be perfect :p)

Thanks,

Gaël

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from collections import Counter
lst = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bli', 'bli']
x = Counter(lst)
max = max(Counter(lst).values())
result_lst = []
for i in range(max):
    for key in x.keys():
        if x[key]:
            result_lst.append(key)
            x[key] -= 1

print result_lst
```

Comment: interesting approach but this not solve my problem.
IN (more complex exaemple): 
`['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bli', 'bli', 'bla']`
output expected / accepted: 
`['foo', 'bar', 'bli', 'bla', 'foo', 'bar', 'bli', 'foo']`

Comment: take a look at my edit.